# Find the optimal regularization parameter λ for each of the polynomials of degree 0, 1, 2, . . . , 10. Plot that graph. Do it in python

Tags: python, regression

I am using RidgeCV function from the library scikit learn to find the optimum regularization parameter in a given range in ridge regression.I have created true output and stored it in numpy array t[] by adding noise. I have input values in X[] which contains k elements. For each k element we generate L noise values which is normal distribution giving k*L instances of t.

```
    ridge=make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(i),RidgeCV(alphas = lambdas, fit_intercept=False))
    ridge.fit(X[:, None], t)
```

However I am getting the following error while executing this:

```
Enter the Number k:8
Enter the Number L:1
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:952: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      w = ((v + alpha) ** -1) - (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:953: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      w[constant_column] = - (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:955: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      c = np.dot(U, self._diag_dot(w, UT_y)) + (alpha ** -1) * y
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:955: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
      c = np.dot(U, self._diag_dot(w, UT_y)) + (alpha ** -1) * y
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:956: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      G_diag = self._decomp_diag(w, U) + (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:956: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
      G_diag = self._decomp_diag(w, U) + (alpha ** -1)
    Polynomial of degree 1 and lambda_optimum =0.0 is:[nan nan]
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:952: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      w = ((v + alpha) ** -1) - (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:953: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      w[constant_column] = - (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:955: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      c = np.dot(U, self._diag_dot(w, UT_y)) + (alpha ** -1) * y
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:955: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
      c = np.dot(U, self._diag_dot(w, UT_y)) + (alpha ** -1) * y
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:956: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      G_diag = self._decomp_diag(w, U) + (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:956: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
      G_diag = self._decomp_diag(w, U) + (alpha ** -1)
    Polynomial of degree 2 and lambda_optimum =0.0 is:[nan nan nan]
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:952: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      w = ((v + alpha) ** -1) - (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:953: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      w[constant_column] = - (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:955: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      c = np.dot(U, self._diag_dot(w, UT_y)) + (alpha ** -1) * y
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:955: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
      c = np.dot(U, self._diag_dot(w, UT_y)) + (alpha ** -1) * y
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:956: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
      G_diag = self._decomp_diag(w, U) + (alpha ** -1)
    C:\Users\Sankalp\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\ridge.py:956: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
      G_diag = self._decomp_diag(w, U) + (alpha ** -1)
```

Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your posted code has three blocking points for me: (1) It fails to run as posted.  (2) Your code requires manual input; please provide an example that shows the error on its own.  (3) The code is not minimal; you've given us the entire program, rather than reducing it to the expected minimal case.

Comment: I am getting error while using RidgeCV() function. It is not able to find me optimal regularization parameter. Can you please help?

Comment: I have edited it for input k=8, L=1.. Please see above. Error is in this line: ridge=make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(i),RidgeCV(alphas = lambdas, fit_intercept=False))

Comment: No, your posted code still asks for input.  Also, it's not at all minimal.

Comment: I have edited my code. Kindly see above. I think it is minimal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no errors in your posting.  You have *warnings*; the term means that the software believes that it has a path to continue.  I munged your posting enough to get results:

```
Polynomial of degree 7 and lambda_optimum =0.0 is:[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
Polynomial of degree 8 and lambda_optimum =0.005 is:[ 0.39440842  0.15084343 -3.20466228 -0.90279433  0.59119079  1.1348398
  1.08897586  0.72688052  0.22113213]
Polynomial of degree 9 and lambda_optimum =0.005 is:[ 0.39444127  0.1573405  -3.22312401 -0.9214617   0.58848021  1.15542306
  1.134718    0.79660069  0.31211144 -0.21590847]
Polynomial of degree 10 and lambda_optimum =0.005 is:[ 0.39403704  0.18160145 -3.25882822 -0.9706416   0.56285357  1.17181052
  1.19935923  0.90873149  0.46728508 -0.02381393 -0.5059829 ]
```

Is that sufficient?

If you *need* to eliminate the warnings, then you'll need to dig into the algorithm to find out how the zero denominators get their values.  The problem may be a natural result of your input -- such as supplying zero coefficients for leading, unused terms (such as x^10 when you're fitting only a 9th-degree polynomial).  Start by printing out the arguments you send into the problem function; then hand-simulated the algorithm and see where you get zero division.

Comment: On which platform did you run it? I mean on which editor? I still get these errors.

Comment: I did not run in an editor; I ran from the console on a CentOS system.  I did get all of your warnings, but no errors, followed by the output I posted.

Comment: the code is still giving optimal lambda as nan for all all polynomials for the errors

Comment: by any chance did you make any modifications in the code ?

Comment: Yes; I ripped out all of the inapplicable `plt` commands; they don't contribute to the problem case.

Comment: It is still giving me optimal value of lambda as nan for every polynomial degree. How are you getting finite values for the same code?

Comment: I still don't know where I'm going wrong. Can you paste the modified code here

Comment: Not any more; it's long gone, overwritten from other answers.  If you post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll try to reproduce it.